# SDK: Tencent TBS, Flutter app rejected from play store

Tags: flutter, sdk, tencent

Android app rejected every time due to unknown reason of SDK: Tencent TBS. I am using following packages in my flutter app.

```
 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.10
  simple_animations: ^5.0.2
  pin_code_fields: ^8.0.1
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.9
  provider: ^6.1.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.2
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.4
  http: ^1.2.0
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
  uuid: ^4.3.3
  device_info_plus: ^9.1.0
  firebase_core: ^2.24.2
  firebase_auth: ^4.7.2
  firebase_app_check: ^0.2.1+8
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.4.8
  app_links: ^3.4.5
  intl: ^0.19.0
  flutter_email_sender: ^6.0.2
  flutter_file_view: ^2.2.1
  email_validator: ^2.1.17
  connectivity_plus: ^5.0.2
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
  flutter_linkify: ^6.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.2.4
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.3.2
  path_provider: ^2.1.2
  sn_progress_dialog: ^1.1.3
  jumping_dot: ^0.0.6
  crypto: ^3.0.3
```

I upgraded all packages used in the app, I filled up the play store data security form. But app was rejected every time due to an unknown reason of SDK: Tencent TBS.
Can anyone help me to resolve the issue? Help would be appratiated. Thanks